# How to add a View above the display Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, jquery-animate

I want to create a translate animation which will pop up a View from the top of the screen. Now I need to put my view above the screen , so that it will be invisible . The root of all Views is a vertical `LinearLayout` . This is how I inflate the `RelativeLayout` (which is going to be animated) into my LinearLayout.

```
final LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.mainLayout);
final RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)   
LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.animated_layout , 
            root , false );

root.addView(container);
```

and this is the Relativelayout xml .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="70dp"
  android:background="@drawable/list_item_back1" >

<TextView 
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ass you said, become your view invisible. Then, create an XML translate animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <translate 
       android:fromYDelta="100%" 
       android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

In your java code do something like this:

```
Animation translateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),    R.anim.translate_animation); 
translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
      yourAnimatedView.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
  }
  yourAnimatedView.startAnimation(translateAnimation);  
  });
```

Comment: How can I make it to appear from the top of the screen . And appear above other views not filling the linear layout ?